# Looking for 1980s/90s Scifi Book, Mind Control, Man protecting his Daughter, Psychics

Tags: story-identification, books, psychic, mind-control

This could be a book 2 of a series.

The book was from some time in the 1980s or 90's. Dark cover with a title of "*something* Minds". example. "Cold Minds" or "Metal Minds" or "Grey Minds".

The main character was a weak psychic or non-psychic. When he was in university he met others who were very powerful psychics. He has a daughter who could be very powerful psychic and the man he went to school with wants to find him so he can steal his daughter.

The evil character and others are able to control and mind read regular people. They use this to be heads of organizations or companies or industry.

The main character's name could be Daniel.

I read this book ~17 years ago.

Not Carrion Comfort by Dan Simmons

Not Firestarter by Steven King

Comment: This sounds like a really bad remembrance of *Firestarter* by Steven King...